# How to disable software keyboard in EditText view and make cursor visible at same time in Android 4.0+?

Tags: java, android, android-keypad

How to disable software keyboard in `EditText` view and make `cursor` visible at same time?

I try all examples on stackoverflow and get two cases:

**1. keyboard is hidden, cursor is hidden**

**2. keyboard is showing, cursor is showing**

But I need keyboard hidden and cursor showing. How do it?

I do next:

```
dialText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(dialText.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }
});

dialText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(dialText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        return false;
    }
});
```

And keyboard still not hidden, when I moving cursor, keyboard is appearing again.

**This issue is only on Android version 4.0+.**

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your manifest file in activity tag:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ExampleActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
</activity>
```

Comment: Ok use this code:

editText_input_field.setOnTouchListener(otl);

private OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true; // the listener has consumed the event
    }
 };

Answer (score 1):

Do this things in on focus event. You have implement on focus event for EditText and check hasFocus object is true then show the keyboard and cursor otherwise hide it

Answer (score 1):

Implement `FocusListener` and hide keyboard using `InputMethodManager` class's `hideSoftInputFromInputMethod`.

Comment: Have you tried hideSoftInputFromWindow using flag HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS?

Answer (score 1):

```
View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
        };

dialText.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity    
    ... 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
    ...
</activity>
```